# xcode: missing file xcdatamodeld after changing the path of file

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I `added` a data model to my project and found a bundle `users.xcdatamodeld` in my project directory. after that I `moved under a sub directory` of the project. also `moved physically`. and after that when I compiled, xcode `shows missing file` error.

Any help on this will be thankful.

Comment: Did you find out, how to solve this. If so, please share the fix. I am running into same problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the file from the file list in xcode (it should be in red text) then go to add File->Add File to "Project" and add the file back to your project.